# Taking derivative of function $g: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ defined in terms of $f: \mathbb{R}^{n+1} \to \mathbb{R}$.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative

Suppose we are given $g(r): \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ where $g(r) = f(ry, r^2s)$ for $f: \mathbb{R}^{n+1} \to \mathbb{R}$ where $y \in \mathbb{R}^n, s \in \mathbb{R}$. How do we determine $\frac{dg}{dr}$? I have a feeling some sort of Chain Rule might be useful.

In addition, this problem looks very much like the definition of the directional derivative of $\underline{q}$ in the direction of $\underline{v}$ as $p'(0)$ where $p(t) = q(\underline{a} + t\underline{v})$. Is there a similar geometric intuition for what $\frac{dg}{dr}$ is doing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm supposing $y$ and $s$ are fixed. Then, $g$ is a composition $g=f\circ h$ where $f$ is as advertised and

$h:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R^{n+1}$ is defined by $r\mapsto (ry,r^{2}s)$.

Then, the chain rule applies to say that $$\left ( \frac{\mathrm{d} g}{\mathrm{d} r} \right )_{r=r_{0}}=\nabla f(h(r_{0}))\cdot \left ( \frac{\mathrm{d} h}{\mathrm{d} r} \right )_{r=r_{0}}$$ which is, after calculating the derivatives, $$\sum ^{n}_{i=1}y_{i}\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_{i}}(r_{0}y,r_{0}^{2}s)+2r_{0}s\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_{n+1}}(r_{0}y,r_{0}^{2}s)$$

Comment: Ah, your definition of $h$ made the application of the generalized Chain Rule far more clear. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

There is a multivariate chain rule that is somewhat easy to remember that solves this quite nicely. Let $g_1,g_2,\dots,g_m:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ be continuously differentiable, and let $f:\mathbb{R}^m\to\mathbb{R}$ be differentiable. If $F:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$ such that 
$$F(x_1,\dots,x_n)=f(g_1(x_1,\dots,x_n), g_2(x_1,\dots,x_n), \dots , g_m(x_1,\dots,x_n)),$$ then we have
$$\frac{\partial F}{\partial x_i} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial g_1}\cdot \frac{\partial g_1}{\partial x_i} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial g_2}\cdot\frac{\partial g_2}{\partial x_i} + \cdots \frac{\partial f}{\partial g_m}\cdot\frac{\partial g_m}{\partial x_i}.$$
(I learned this recently from Spivak's Calculus on Manifolds, but uses a different notation so it would be nice if someone could double check this.)

For this problem, we only need it with respect to one variable, so we use
$$ \frac{dF}{dx} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial g_1}\cdot \frac{d g_1}{dx} + \cdots + \frac{\partial f}{\partial g_{n+1}} \cdot \frac{ dg_{n+1}}{dx}. $$
We get
$$\frac{dg}{dr} = D_1f(ry, r^2s)\cdot y_1 + D_2f(ry,r^2s)\cdot y_2 +\cdots + D_nf(ry, r^2s)\cdot y_n+  D_{n+1}f(ry, r^2s) \cdot 2rs,$$
where $D_i f$ is the $i$th partial derivative of $f$. This is the notation used in Spivak's book for partial derivative, but I'm not quite sure if this is standard.

Comment: Since the first variable $y \in \mathbb{R}^n$, does that mean $f_1' = \nabla_y f$?

Comment: No. Remember how in the normal chain rule, we assume that the function doesn't compose anything and take the normal derivative, and then multiply by the derivative of the composed function. We're doing the same thing here.

Comment: But isn't the partial derivative $D_yf(x)$ equivalent to $\nabla f \cdot y$?

Comment: Hm... you're confusing me with notation. What does $\nabla_yf$ mean? If it is the first component of $\nabla f$ then yes, but I'm not quite sure what the subscript $y$ is for.

Comment: Ah.. I see where I made the mistake. I'll fix my answer.